# Maintaining rounded corners when the height is less than twice the border radius?

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface, qwidget

In Qt you can use CSS stylesheets to give a `QWidget` a rounded corner:

```
QWidget#myWidget {
    background-color: #ffbb33;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

[image: QWidget with rounded edges]

I wanted to animate this `QWidget` to show it popping up from the bottom of the screen to notify the user, but found that when the height of the widget is less than the border radius, the rounded edges jarringly disappear.

[image: Animated QWidget showing effect of disappearing rounded edges]

Is it possible to prevent this?

**Update:** I appreciate everyone's web related solutions to this problem. Most of them actually do translate pretty well to this application. But I do just want to point out that this application is coded in `C++` with `Qt` libraries. If you have other web-related solutions, please do post them, but be aware that if you're using web technologies to do this, then "It works for me" isn't exactly applicable in this case. ;)

Comment: How are you animating this?

Comment: Using a `QPropertyAnimation` that changes the `minimumHeight` of the `QWidget`

Comment: Why not animate the border radius from 0 or 5px up to 20px?

Comment: This is a good idea. I think that would probably work. I would still like to understand why it behaves as is though... I've written a rather simple custom rounded-edge drawing algorithm myself, and it handled cases like this quite naturally.

Comment: My **GUESS** would be the way CSS/browser paints the borders.  If there isn't sufficient room it reverts to the default.

Comment: @hungerstar That's my guess as well.

Comment: hungerstar is right. unfortunately the stylesheet takes the easy way out when there's insufficient room

Comment: I'd animate the width as well, and keep it centered.  For the first `40px` it would grow `80px` in width, and the radius would smoothly grow from `0px` to `20px` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set the `bottom` CSS property to its negative height, and then animate the `bottom` property to 0, rather than `height`? [See this fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/puVxS/). This way you don't have to mess with the height of the element, and there won't be any weird squishing of the content, either.

Comment: This does look like an acceptable alternative, but it is still just a workaround rather than solving the actual issue. (I'm not 100% sure the actual issue can be solved anyway.) Also, it *is* visually distinct from changing the height of the object.

Comment: @CoryKlein True, it is different in appearance (and actually I think it looks better because I don't particularly like the squished look). However, I also can't reproduce the problem you're having. Does the border-radius disappear in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/bWbnK/

Comment: You probably can't reproduce this because I am implementing this in `C++` and `Qt` and you aren't. `Qt` is likely what is doing the drawing of the sharp edges, not a web browser.

Comment: @CoryKlein Ah you're right, guess I didn't notice the `C++` tag.

Comment: I marked this as the accepted answer because this solution worked best when translated to Qt C++. Animating the border-radius did not work because there was too much of a delay between changing the stylesheet and the appearance in the UI updating so the animation was laggy.

Answer (score 2):

You could animate the corners.  Start small or no border radius and build up to what you need.  You may not be using jQuery but you could do something similar.

*CSS*

```css
#myWidget {
     border-radius: 5px;
}
```

*jQuery*

```js
$('#myWidget').animate({ 'border-radius': '20px' }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using QPropertyAnimation, you can set up an animation in parallel to your resizing animation that animates the rounded border going from radius 0px to 20px (or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

one thing you could do is to reimplement the QWidget's `resizeEvent`, and there, calculate the maximum availabe size for the borders. Then set the border radius using `this.setStyleSheet("border-radius: ?px");` (replacing ? for the result, ovbiously)

You can check here how to reimplement a function: [`https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/cpp-function-overriding/`](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/cpp-function-overriding/), where BaseClass is QWidget and DerivedClass is the new widget, which you could call QRoundedCornersWidget.